# ColdFusion 2016 - Upload .mp4

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cffile

I am getting 404 File or Directory Not Found trying to upload a mp4 file.

When I switch to a .png all works fine.

Thoughts? I have increased my file post size to 250MB. It is a 150MB Video
I have tried Strict = "False" as well.

I tried an 8MB it uploaded fine. So this is a file size setting. Help. I changed the size in ColdFsuion Admin.

```
<cfset destination = expandPath("./videos")>
<CFFILE ACTION="Upload"
  FILEFIELD="form.docfile"
  DESTINATION="#destination#"
  STRICT="false" 
  ACCEPT="video/mp4," 
  NAMECONFLICT="makeunique"
>
```

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

When I switch to just a normal file like a DOC/PDF/JPG/PNG all works fine

```
ACCEPT="application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, text/plain, application/pdf, application/octet-stream, image/png, image/jpg, image/pjpeg, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-png,"
```

Comment: What update version of CF 2016 are you running?  With Update 10 they added a new attribute `allowedExtensions` and a new admin setting for blocked extensions.  Check those for your environment. [See the release notes here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2016-update-10.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using IIS, here is something you can check.

Please add the appropriate mimeType and restart IIS.

Your web.config file should have one of these entries.
I'd recommend adding it using the wizard; please see.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mov" mimeType="video/quicktime" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".movie" mimeType="video/x-sgi-movie" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp2" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mpa" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mpe" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mpeg" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mpg" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".wmv" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmv" />
```

Comment: Those mime types are in there.